# Class in java - How can I print all the array With all details after sorting

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have a problem with exercise, I try to sort the array of allLecturers by Num Of Times Pen Falls.

I put all Num Of Times Pen Falls each lecturer in a temporary array and then sort the array using a function and then want to print out a sorted array allLecturers.

How can I print after sorting the array allLecturers he displayed sorted?

this is the function:

```
public void sortingEmployee() {
    int[] arr = new int[allLecturers.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < allLecturers.length; i++) {
        if (allLecturers[i] == null)
            break;
        arr[i] = allLecturers[i].getNumOfTimesPenFalls();

    }
    selectionSort(arr);

 }
```

**college class:**

```
public class College extends Lecturer {
    private String name;
    private int numOfLecturers;
    public Lecturer[] allLecturers;
    private int index;

    public College(String name, int numOfLecturers, int MaxLecturers) {
        this.name = name;
        this.numOfLecturers = numOfLecturers;
        this.allLecturers = new Lecturer[MaxLecturers];
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setNumOfLecturers(int numOfLecturers) {
        this.numOfLecturers = numOfLecturers;
    }

    public int getNumOfLecturers() {

        return this.numOfLecturers;
    }

    public void setAllLecturers(Lecturer[] allLecturers) {
        this.allLecturers = allLecturers;
    }

    public Lecturer[] getAllLecturers() {
        return this.allLecturers;
    }

    public void addEmployee(String name, int numOfTimesPenFalls, String favoriteIceCream, int automaticNum) {

        allLecturers[index] = new Lecturer(name, numOfTimesPenFalls, favoriteIceCream, automaticNum);
        index++;
    }

    public void sortingEmployee() {
        int[] arr = new int[allLecturers.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < allLecturers.length; i++) {
            if (allLecturers[i] == null) break;
            arr[i] = allLecturers[i].getNumOfTimesPenFalls();

        }
        selectionSort(arr);

    }

    public void selectionSort(int[] arr) {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
            int min = i;
            for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
                if (arr[j] < arr[min]) {
                    min = j;
                }
            }
            if (i != min) {
                int swap = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[min];
                arr[min] = swap;
            }
        }
    }

    public void print() {
        for (int i = 0; i < allLecturers.length; i++) {
            if (allLecturers[i] == null) break;
            System.out.println(allLecturers[i]);
        }

    }
}
```

**Lecturer class:**

```
public class Lecturer {
    private String name;
    private int numOfTimesPenFalls;
    private String favoriteIceCream;
    private int automaticNum;

    public Lecturer() {

    }

    public Lecturer(String name, int numOfTimesPenFalls, String favoriteIceCream, int automaticNum) {
        this.name = name;
        this.numOfTimesPenFalls = numOfTimesPenFalls;
        this.favoriteIceCream = favoriteIceCream;
        this.automaticNum = automaticNum;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setNumOfTimesPenFalls(int numOfTimesPenFalls) {

        this.numOfTimesPenFalls = numOfTimesPenFalls;
    }

    public int getNumOfTimesPenFalls() {
        return this.numOfTimesPenFalls;
    }

    public void setFavoriteIceCream(String favoriteIceCream) {
        this.favoriteIceCream = favoriteIceCream;
    }
    public String getFavoriteIceCream() {
        return this.favoriteIceCream;
    }

    public void setAutomaticNum(int automaticNum) {
        this.automaticNum = automaticNum;
    }

    public int getAutomaticNum() {
        return this.automaticNum;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "NAME: " + this.name + " ,num Of Times Pen Falls: " + this.numOfTimesPenFalls + " ,favoriteIceCream: " + this.favoriteIceCream + " ,Automatic Number: " + this.automaticNum;
    }
}
```

**main class:**

```
public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        College c1 = new College("College1", 3, 4);

        Lecturer L1 = new Lecturer("david", 5, "apple", 1001);
        Lecturer L2 = new Lecturer("yosi", 5, "apple", 1001);

        c1.addEmployee("yosi", 5, "apple", 1001);
        c1.addEmployee("david", 3, "apple", 1001);
        c1.addEmployee("liran", 8, "apple", 1001);

        c1.print();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried ```System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));```? Also, this question contains too much code, please narrow it down to the essentials, or make an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: A college is not a lecturer. So it should not extend Lecturer.